# Cut graph at a given edge and return remaining subgraphs?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, graphs-and-networks

I would like to have a function that removes an edge from a graph and returns all remaining graphs after the operation. For example for a graph like

```
gr = Graph[{UndirectedEdge[y1, y2], UndirectedEdge[y2, y3], 
     UndirectedEdge[y2, y4], UndirectedEdge[y5, y3], 
     UndirectedEdge[y6, y3]}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

> [image]

It should return when splitting at the `y2-y3` edge:

```
split[gr,UndirectedEdge[y2, y3]]
```

> {
>
> Graph[{UndirectedEdge[y1, y2], UndirectedEdge[y2, y4]}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
>
> ,
>
> Graph[{UndirectedEdge[y5, y3], UndirectedEdge[y6, y3]}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
>
> }

Or, it should return when splitting at the `y1-y2` edge:

```
split[gr,UndirectedEdge[y1, y2]]
```

> {
>
> Graph[{y1}, {}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
>
> ,
>
> Graph[{ UndirectedEdge[y2, y3], UndirectedEdge[y2, y4], UndirectedEdge[y5, y3], UndirectedEdge[y6, y3]}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
>
> }

Is there a function in Mathematica that can do this? What is a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gr2 = EdgeDelete[gr, UndirectedEdge[y2, y3]]
```

[image]

```
ConnectedComponents[gr2]
```

(*

{{y3, y5, y6}, {y1, y2, y4}}

*)

or `ConnectedGraphComponents[gr2]`

[image]

Comment: That seems to return a single graph of two disconnected components. Can one get a list of several diconnected graphs instead?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it: `ConnectedGraphComponents[EdgeDelete[gr, UndirectedEdge[y2, y3]]]`. Thank you for pointing this out!